Direct Analogue of Ideal Product in Groups
The Notion of Ideals in Ring Theory can be seen, from the perspective of homomorphisms, as the direct analogue of Normal Subgroups in Group Theory. There are various instances where Sum and Intersections of Ideals in Rings can be seen as direct analogue of Product and Intersection of Normal Subgroups in Groups.
For instance, let $I,J \subseteq R$ and $H,K \unlhd G$ we have the second isomorphism theorems:
$$ (I+J) / I  \simeq J/(I \cap J) $$
$$ HK/H \simeq K/(H\cap K) $$
Question: What is the direct analogue of Product of Ideals in Rings to Groups?
My Attempt: 
Upon considering left and right Absorption criterion for Ideal ( $ rI \subseteq I $ and $ Ir \subseteq I $ ) as an analogue of conjugation invariance criterion for normal subgroup (
$ gHg^{-1} \subseteq H $ ) , it seemed plausible to me that the Commutator of subgroups defined as:
$$ [H,K] = \langle \{ [h,k] \ | \ h\in H \ \& \ k \in K \} \rangle $$
where $\langle S\rangle$ refers to subgroup generated by S, should be the required analog of ideal product in groups.
For (1) just like in case of ideals we have for normal subgroups the inclusion $ [H,K] \unlhd (H\cap K) $ and (2) it matches with ideal product in Lie Algebras.
Problems:

I'm not able to construct an analog of second isomorphism theorem for it to support this claim. Upon searching I found this relation: $$ (I \cap J)/IJ \simeq Tor_1^R(R/I , R/J)  $$ I'm just getting into studying Homological Algebra and the use of Tor Functor in Rings from Eisenbud so I don't know how to construct an analogue of this in groups.
It should be noted that the condition $ gHg^{-1} \subseteq H $ corresponds to the conjunction of two conditions $ rI \subseteq I $ and $ Ir \subseteq I $. For only one of them (either right or left absorption ) there doesn't seem to be a corresponding condition in groups.

Perhaps another way to look at this problem, for instance a categorical formulation of this, might make it more obvious to see but I'm still learning how to do it.
Any Contribution (some analogue different from my attempt, solution to problem 1 or any other perspective) would be helpful and appreciated.
UPDATE 1: Even though the Idea in comment using modified Augmentation Ideals didn't work in it's obvious form, I'm hopeful. The wikipedia article for Augmentation Ideal says $$ I_G/I_G^2 = G/[G,G] $$ which doesn't seem to translate directly to an Analogue either but it might help us going with something.

the Tor approach should involve non Abelian cohomology  so it might be a bit harder. About the categorical approach, $IJ$ is the image of $I\times J\to R$, but the image of $H\ast K\to G$ is $HK$, so the coproduct analogy doesn't work. See this question about the ideal product.

sorry I meant \otimes instead of \times in my previous comment

If $H \subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup, we have an ideal in the group ring $I_H \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[G]$ defined as the kernel of $\mathbb{Z}[G] \to \mathbb{Z}[G/H]$. It consists of those $\sum_g z(g) g$ such that for every coset $gH$ we have $\sum_{g' \in gH} z(g')=0$. Now, does the product $I_H \cdot I_K$ again have the form $I_{\text{something}}$? If yes, we have a possible candidate.

@MartinBrandenburg Taking $ G = H = \mathbb{Z}_2 $, then $I_H$ is basically the Augmentation Ideal and we have $ I_H^2 = 2I_H$ which does NOT  have any corresponding form of $I_K$ for any $K \unlhd \mathbb{Z}_2$
